# How can I install Tilix on Deepin 15.11 properly?

Tags: debian, package-management, deepin, tilix

I installed Tilix by using:

```
wget https://github.com/gnunn1/tilix/releases/download/1.9.3/tilix.zip -P $HOME/Downloads
sudo unzip $HOME/Downloads/tilix.zip -d /
sudo glib-compile-schemas /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/
```

After running tilix in Terminal I get:

```
object.Exception@../../../.dub/packages/gtk-d-3.8.5/gtk-d/generated/gtkd/gtkd/Loader.d(125): Library load failed (libvte-2.91.so.0): libvte-2.91.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I went for the manual installation because

```
sudo apt install tilix
```

leads to

```
E: Unable to locate package tilix
```

How can I solve this problem?

*Edit: Other approaches.*

Doing

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt install tilix
```

returns the same error, and

```
apt-cache search tilix
```

returns nothing.

Content of */etc/apt/sources.list*:

```
## Generated by deepin-installer
deb [by-hash=force] http://packages.deepin.com/deepin lion main contrib non-free
# deb-src http://packages.deepin.com/deepin lion main contrib non-free
```

Files in */etc/apt/sources.list.d*:

```
brave-browser-release.list
sublime-text.list
transmissionbt-ubuntu-ppa-groovy.list
brave-browser-release.list.save
sublime-text.list.save
transmissionbt-ubuntu-ppa-groovy.list.save
```

Doing

```
wget http://packages.deepin.com/deepin/pool/main/t/tilix/tilix-common_1.7.9-2_all.deb
wget http://packages.deepin.com/deepin/pool/main/t/tilix/tilix_1.7.9-2_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i tilix-common_1.7.9-2_all.deb  
sudo dpkg -i tilix_1.7.9-2_amd64.deb 
sudo apt install -f
```

leads to:

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of tilix:
 tilix depends on libgtkd-3-0 (>= 3.8.2); however:
  Package libgtkd-3-0 is not installed.
 tilix depends on libphobos2-ldc-shared78 (>= 1:1.8.0); however:
  Package libphobos2-ldc-shared78 is not installed.
 tilix depends on libvted-3-0 (>= 3.8.2); however:
  Package libvted-3-0 is not installed.
```

---

**Solution**

I did

```
sudo apt install apt-file
sudo apt-file update
```

And `apt-file search libvte-2.91.so.0` shows

```
libvte-2.91-0: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvte-2.91.so.0
libvte-2.91-0: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvte-2.91.so.0.4600.1
```

After this, the following worked:

```
wget https://github.com/gnunn1/tilix/releases/download/1.9.3/tilix.zip -P $HOME/Downloads
sudo unzip $HOME/Downloads/tilix.zip -d /
sudo glib-compile-schemas /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/
```

Comment: Tilix is actually available in the Deepin repositories: http://packages.deepin.com/deepin/pool/main/t/tilix/ (you could just download the .deb from there and install with `dpkg`, but this really shouldn't be necessary). First, try running `sudo apt update` and then `sudo apt install tilix`. Does that work? If not, please [edit] your question and show us the contents of your `/etc/apt/sources.list` and any files in the `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` directory. Also show us the output of `apt-cache search tilix` after running `apt update`.

Comment: Hello. I've updated the question.

Comment: I deleted my answer since it doesn't solve your issue. It looks like the package isn't actually available for your version of tilix after all. The only thing I can suggest is to [edit] your question to include the output of the commands we tried together and hope someone else can help you.